# Changes to dependancy Java classes do not take effect until Main .java file is touched

Tags: java, netbeans

I had give a lot of search on this.. I have a problem that can be summarized with this code:

```
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JDialog ui = new RandomDialog();
    }
});
```

`item` is just a menu Item and `RandomDialog` is a class that extends `JDialog`.

Every time I made a change in `RandomDialog` class, I had to "update" the `ui` declaration from `JDialog` to `RandomDialog` and then vice-versa.

What is the problem?

[EDIT]

I have a `JFrame`, with a `JMenuBar` and `JMenuItem`. One of these Items had a listener like the one above. I want to open a `JDialog` when that item is pressed. What happens is every time I make a change on the code from the class that represents that `JDialog` (a separate class that extends `JDialog`) that change is not presented unless I change the declaration of the `JDialog`. So imagine that I have the declaration like this:

```
JDialog ui = new RandomDialog();
```

If I make a change, I have to put like this:

```
RandomDialog ui = new RandomDialog();
```

And next I have to put again:

```
JDialog ui = new RandomDialog();
```

And so on, so on...

Comment: Please be more specific regarding your question. It is unclear for me atleast. Highly appreciate, if you will add more input to the question for better clarity of thoughts :-)

Answer (score 0):

By changing `JDialog` to `RandomDialog` and then back to `JDialog` you are not changing the code, but you are changing the timestamp of the file.  This causes your build system to rebuild the `.class` file from the Java file, build `.jar` file, and then possibly deploy it to a server, depending on how you have it set up.

The cause of the problem is that your build system does not realize that this file (with the `JMenuItem`) depends on the other file (with the `RandomDialog`) so changes to the `RandomDialog` are not causing a rebuild to be done.

To solve this, you will need to look at your project structure.  You have not described how the code is being built.  Usually if you use an IDE, it will let you manage project dependencies.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. It's just a simple project, nothing big deal. How can I do such thing like "manage project dependencies" in order to make the code work every time without the need to change the declaration? (P.S. I know that changing it is not a code change, but it's the only way that I can make it work)

Comment: In NetBeans Clean & Build usually takes care of this. Do you have Compile On Save enabled?

Comment: I will give it a try. No, I don't have. Should I enable it?

Comment: Someone?

I have to change something in my class every time I want to make changes visible.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans Clean & Build usually will do the necessary re-build.

Be sure to enable *Compile On Save*

[image]